# Yevamot with karet?

Tags: yibbum-chalitza-levirate, masechet-yevamot, karet

Is the mandate of yibbum suspended for a man whose soul is punished with karet, for it is stated the purpose of yibbum “The first child that she bears shall be accounted to the dead brother, that his name may not be blotted out in Israel.” Deutoronomy 25:6. Since Keritot has the purpose of excising some sins from the Jewish community, are those who violate karet level punishments and don’t repent for it not requiring of yibbum? Is this found somewhere in the Talmud of yevamot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tur (Even Ha’ezer 157) brings down an argument regarding a sinner in general, and Shulchan Aruch (Even Ha’ezer 157:5) rules that Yibbum is still required, and does not make a distinction between one who is punishable by Karet and one who is not.

Furthermore, we only exempt the woman from Yibbum, because of that verse when his name was destined to be blotted out from when he was born, i.e. he was born unable to have children (Even Ha’ezer 172:3)